# WAR file can't be deployed on Tomcat 7 without wtpwebapps folder

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I am facing a problem by deploying a War file on a Tomcat Server.
My Tomcat Server configuration as follows:

[image: tomcat config]

My steps to deploy:

1. I created a WAR file in Eclipse Kepler (Windows 7 64 bit, no Maven used).
2. Uploaded it with a Tomcat Web Application Manager.
3. Clicked deploy.

Tomcat unpacks WAR file in tomcat/webapps and throws me NullPointerException. It is missing some files that should be imported to project to work it right.

When I was working in Eclipse, as a source for these files I gave a workspace path, given in the Server settings and adding the wtpwebapps folder, which was offered by Eclipse by default. So my complete path looks like this:

> C:\Users\myUserName\kepler\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\myProjectName\WEB-INF\classes\project\fdsProject\FDS.prj

Now, when I deploy the project, it locates in a **webapps** folder, not in **wtpwebapps** and if I try to start in a browser, it shows me NullPointerException. But as soon as I copy the wtpwebapps folder from my workspace to the tomcat installation folder, near webapps, my project is starting successfully.

It means that I cannot start my project on another server, just deploying a standalone WAR file. I must add manually the wtpwebapps with my project in into the tomcat server installation folder. How can I optimize it and start project just with a WAR file deployed? 
Thank you!

**EDIT**

My project structure is looking like this:
[image: project structure]

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I posted a screenshot of my server configuration, no code presented in this issue

Comment: What's the NPE stack trace? How are you referring to those files?

Comment: Using the absolute path, starting from catalina base: `private static String data_path = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base")).getAbsolutePath()+"\\webapps\\myProjectName\\WEB-INF\\classes\\project\\fdsProject\\"` and so on.

Comment: Well there's your problem right there.

Comment: `new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base")).getAbsolutePath()` gives a path to the tomcat installation folder, where the webapps and my WAR file is located independing of my computer setting. Where exactly can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop the Tomcat Server
2. In the settings view `Tomcat Server settings in Eclipse -> Server 
   Locations`, check `Use Tomcat Installation(...）`
3. Now, you can change the `Deploy Path`, if you want `webapps`, then input it.

**EDIT**

The values below control how tomcat deal with war file

```
autoDeploy="true"
unpackWARs="true"
```

Just search these values in your `server.xml` file and edit values as you need.

Comment: After adding new server Settings, near my Project appeared a new Project "Servers". Do I need to include it somehow to a WAR file of my project?

Comment: After editing and saving your Server, you can use `Run on Server ...` context menu to use it

Comment: Well I tried as you said. As a result: 1) eclipse creates a new folder with my project name in a tomcat/webapps, when I "Run on Server" in Eclipse 2) I created WAR file from a project and deployed it on a Tomcat. 3) Tomcat created in tomcat/webapps near my project's folder a new folder based on a WAR and I could run the new added WAR application. 4) After that I decided to test it on another machine. I copied the project folder to a new location and deployed the war file. So I had the same files as on the first machine. And it didn't work! Without adding a project folder it doesnt work as well

Comment: Tomcat always unzip war to a directory with the name as the war file as a default work mode

Comment: Yes, it does in my case as well. In tomcat/webapps I have "myProjectName", which was generated after I ran my project on a Server, the WAR file say "test.war" and a folder test. But the names of a war file and of my project are different. I think it does not make much sense. So I am confused now, how to run it on another machine that it really works just from a single WAR file.

Comment: Anyways it works fine with the wtpwebapps folder, so if I dont't find any solution for standalone WAR I will keep using this working solution. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to deploy your app as a WAR file, you need to refer to everything within it relative to the app itself, not with absolute file paths, not even as file paths if you can. If you have code that requires a `java.io.File`, rewrite it. The point is that you don't care *where* things are, you just care about how to get to their *contents*. For a Servlet, you can read anything on the web app's classpath by calling `getResourceAsStream()` on the correct class or classloader.

See [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream) .

Comment: thanks for the issues, you left me. I've read them and try to build my path now. But it seems that I am doing something wrong, as I get null as a result. I edited my question and put my project structure here. I am trying to reach the fdsProject folder, to get its path as a String and to submit it to a next variable. What I am doing is: `InputStream path = CBREngine.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/project/fdsProject/FDS.prj");` After that I need to convert InputStream to string i guess.

Comment: With `src` as an entry on the Java Build Path, it becomes an entry on the runtime CLASSPATH, so you don't use it as part of the relative reference. You're on the right track, though. Use a Reader to decode the InputStream into text.

Comment: Nice to hear that. I customised my code and tried to convert it to text as you wrote, but what I see are just unreadable symbols. I am probably missing something... My code looks like that:`InputStream path = CBREngine.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/project/fdsProject/FDS.prj");Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(path); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader); String dataPath = null; while ((dataPath=br.readLine())!=null) { System.out.println("Data path: " +dataPath); }`

Comment: Sounds like either a file encoding problem, or the file doesn't contain what you think it does. Might be time for a new Question.

Comment: I actually just need a path to that file as a string, not to open the file. This will be done in the next step if I provide a right path to it. Is a parameter which I give to getResourceAsStream() function correct? Maybe the first slash before project folder is needless?

Comment: I reduced my source path to `InputStream path = CBREngine.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/project/fdsProject");` and see the files in a folder, but not a full path to them.